# Devo criar uma class para cada "input", ou apenas métodos de uma class "form" são o suficiente?

Tags: php, html, orientação-a-objetos

Pois bem, estou com uma dúvida lógica. Comecei a aprender PHP OO recentemente, então essa questão é mais para fins educativos do que qualquer outra coisa.

Meu objetivo é criar uma *class* "form" que irá construir formulários HTML. Esta *class* terá atributos como "id", "name", "method" e "action" e métodos como `openForm()` - para iniciar o formulário com tais atributos, `closeForm()` - para fechar o formulário, e os padrões como *set* e *get* para os atributos.

Minha ideia inicial era criar métodos para cada *input* deste formulário nesta mesma *class*, como por exemplo `newInputText()`, que criaria um *input* do tipo texto, `newButtonSubmit()`, que criaria um botão *submit* e assim por diante (vale notar que cada um destes métodos teria seus próprios parâmetros HTML como "id", "name", "class" e assim por diante).

Minha dúvida é: a criação dos *inputs* e *buttons*, por exemplo, deve se dar através de métodos da *class* "form", OU eu deveria criar uma nova *class* separada para cada um deles, com seus próprios atributos e métodos? Qual seria a forma mais "otimizada" para tal aplicação?

**Exemplo hipotético de código:**

```
$form1 = new Form("teste", "teste", "#");

$form1->openForm();

$form1->newInput("input1", "input1", "Oi");
$form1->newButtonSubmit("btnSend", "btnSend", "Enviar");

$form1->closeForm();
```

Comment: Normalmente os frameworks usam métodos estáticos pq não tem necessidade de guarda valores, fica algo como `Form::input(array('name' => 'nome', 'id' => 'nome', 'class' => 'css-input'))`

Comment: Costuma ser interessante você generalizar primeiro para depois especificar. Por exemplo, ter o método `Form::input` que gera a *tag* `input`, sendo capaz de lidar com todos as suas propriedades, como método genérico; e, se desejado, criar outros como `Form::inputText` e `Form::inputPassword` que utilizam o método genérico, definindo as propriedades necessárias.

Comment: Tente trabalhar com o uso de Namespaces e Princípio da Responsabilidade Única (onde uma classe deve ter apenas UMA responsabilidade). Pois assim você terá um maior reaproveitamento de código e a manutenção fica menos dolorosa.

Answer (score -3):

"Devo criar uma class para cada "input", ou apenas métodos de uma class "form" são o suficiente?"
O paradigma OO é usado por diversas linguagens.
Ele tem o objetivo de ser extensível e fz com q o programador escreva (-)código.
Os frameworks oo(PHP) existem pra serem utilizados, seguindo suas apis.
Estude a API pra não passar trabalho "reinventando a roda".
Tenho certeza q a API do frm q vc usa já resolveu este problema q vc tem.
*Eu começaria dando uma olhada na documentação da "class Form".
Pra descobrir quais métodos ela possui q são úteis p seu propósito.
Quase sempre tem exemplos úteis p ajudar a entender.

Reinventar a roda é sempre 1 decisão ruim.
Pode n dar problema hoje, mas vai dar amanhã.